# WooCommerce variable product, variants not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build custom woocommerce theme. As per the standard, I am overriding the themes from woocommerce plugin to "mytheme/woocommerce/" directory. All are working fine for simple product but when I added variable product from the admin panel with its variants, variants are not showing in the frontend. I have all the templates in my theme that is responsible for showing product types in "mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/".

I am not getting why variable products are not showing variants. Which logic is responsible for calling product types specific templates in woocommerce? Is there any other format I need to follow for variable products only?

I have search about this issue but could not find any blogs till now. Any help and direction would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I think this will help you: https://www.damiencarbery.com/2017/11/change-woocommerce-variations-layout/
I remember there was something odd about the variations. From what I remember I ended up building the variations with custom code.

Comment: This article only show how to customize variable product. Problem I am facing is that even the product has variable the variants are not shown the product page, seems like its calling simple.php template from add-to-cart folder. Do you have any reference how to build variations with custom code.